# Can Trimble Business Center export projection information in any useable GIS format?

Tags: coordinate-system, trimble

In Trimble Business Center, a surveyor can create a local ground system for a given location easily. For example, when building a bridge, the surveyor can create a ground system based on State Plane so that an engineer can be sure that their design can be built correctly. Later in the project, I'm asked to take external data and project it to this local coordinate system.

Can TBC export a .prj file? If not, can it export any other representation of this custom ground such as WKT that I can then use to create a .prj file, and then project any data into the projects CS?

Currently, my surveyor is only able to show me a screenshot showing the False Easting, False Northing, and scale factor for the local CS. I can incorporate these into a prj file myself, but it is a bit time consuming and prone to errors. I'd like a reliable way for a surveyor to create a custom projection that I can easily use in a GIS.

Comment: Geodatabase? https://youtu.be/v1tpt75TL0E?t=1294

Comment: @Mapperz unfortunately the geodatabases TBC exports are all in geographic coordinate systems; I can't get data out in a projected or local coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Export as a shapefile using local coordinates, the .prj should be there.